# Skip multiple lines in YML Regex

Tags: regex, templates, yaml, field

I am creating YML templates to match files (through Python parsing), and in the YML template I have to enter fields which match from the input file and Python, then converts into a database (CSV file).

But I am facing a problem matching company details. A portion of the file looks like this:

```
COMPANY DETAILS

Date : 01-06-2018

ABC Industries
12-31 Lane
New York

Contact No. 1111
```

And the company is actually ABC Industries. But in the file that I have, the `Date` is coming between the `COMPANY DETAILS` text and the actual company details.

I matched the `Date` as:

```
date: Date :\s+(\d+\-\d+\-\d+)
```

in the YML template file. But I am unable to match the company details.

I am using Regex like this to skip the line starting with the text `DATE`:

```
company: COMPANY DETAILS\s+^(Date :.*)?([A-Za-z\s*]*)\s+Contact No.
```

But it isn't working. Please help me out with a proper Regex which skips any blank lines or the lines which start with `Date :` so that I can extract the proper company details from the text.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT

This problem is solved now.

```
COMPANY DETAILS\s+Date :\s+\d+\-\d+\-\d+\s+([A-Z ]*)\n
```

Did the trick.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually, the connection between the python and yaml is working fine. The problem which bothers me is about writing a regex which would skip lines starting with `Date :`

Comment: Good, so you are parsing that text as text. Do you see that you have `COMAPNY` in the text and `COMPANY` in the regex? Try [`(?m)COMAPNY DETAILS\s+(?:^Date\s*:.*\n\s*)?([\s\S]*?)\s*^Contact No\.`](https://regex101.com/r/VjIpNl/1). See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Qh6Op7).

Comment: I don't know why this regex was not working in yaml. But nonetheless, I figured it out, perhaps I included the initial `Date` in my regex initiator as well and then it worked out fine. `COMPANY DETAILS\s+Date :\s+\d+\-\d+\-\d+\s+([A-Z ]*)\n`. Thanks for your help anyway. :)

Comment: So, you have `BUYER` there? What was your expected output?

Comment: No, that was my mistake, was woking on two files simultaneously with kind of the same problem, I have edited the comment. It extracts `ABC Industries`. I can easily add some more code to extract the complete name and address now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
COMPANY DETAILS\s+Date\s*:.*\s*(.+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VjIpNl/3)

**Details**

- `COMPANY DETAILS` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace
- `Date\s*:` - `Date`, 0+ whitespaces, `:`
- `.*\s*` - a line with any whitespaces after
- `(.+)` - Group 1: the line with the company data.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Qh6Op7):

```
import re
rx = r"COMPANY DETAILS\s+Date\s*:.*\s*(.+)"
s = "COMPANY DETAILS\n\nDate : 01-06-2018\n\nABC Industries\n12-31 Lane\nNew York\n\nContact No. 1111"
m = re.search(rx, s, re.MULTILINE)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => ABC Industries
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.search`

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = """COMAPNY DETAILS

Date : 01-06-2018

ABC Industries
12-31 Lane
New York

Contact No. 1111"""

m = re.search("(?<=COMAPNY DETAILS)(?P<company>.*?(?=Contact))", s, flags=re.DOTALL)
if m:
    print( m.group('company') )
```

**Output:**

```
ABC Industries
12-31 Lane
New York
```

Comment: That is a way in which I can parse lines. But what I am asking is if I can write a regular expression so that yml can extract it as a field. What I am asking is that if I can skip the line stating with ``Date :`` in the regular expression for `company`

Comment: I do not understand your requirement, But try this `m = re.search("(?<=DETAILS)(?P<company>.*?(?=Contact))", s, flags=re.DOTALL)` if you do not need date as the start point.